# How to fetch the top two products for each product type?

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have two models looking like this:

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType)

    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Now I want to fetch the top two products (the two with highest score) from each ProductType.
So if I have **Phones, Computers, TVs** as ProductTypes I want the two best Phones, Computers, TVs.

As I don't even know how to do this in MySQL I've tried searching for the MySQL-solution but the ones I find is extremely complex and this doesn't feel like an extremely complex thing to do.

I am leaning towards making an own model for the top products and have a cronjob to fix this, but I'd like to see if there's an easier solution to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you could make a method inside of the ProductType class that returns the top two results for its products:

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def TopTwoProducts(self):
        return self.product_set.order_by('-score')[0:2]
```

Then you would just do something like:

```
for type in ProductType.objects.all():
    type.TopTwoProducts()
```

Comment: Smart solution, I like it! Thanks.

Comment: i don't get it ... why you use for loop?

Comment: You only use the for loop when it comes time to access the top two products (such as listing them in a template or whatever else).

Answer (score 4):

While adam's solution is correct, a more django-ish way would be to use a manager.

See [Managers versus class methods](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/feb/25/managers/) on James Bennett's blog

Among other advantages :

- a manager carries all query-specific code, while avoiding to clutter the model class
- the same manager class can be shared among several classes
- the manager can be used directly on a model class, or via a one-to-many or m2m relation

Thus, for the above question :

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.manager import Manager

class ProductScoreManager(Manager):

    use_for_related_field = True

    def top_score(self, limit=2):
        return self.get_query_set().order_by('-score')[:limit]
```

Then add this manager class as *default manager* for Product :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = ProductScoreManager()
    ...
```

Now, thanks to *objects* overriding the default manager, and *use_for_related_field* allowing its use in relation queries, the top_score method can be used in any model related to products.

```
myproducttype = ProductType.objects.get(...)
myproducttype.products.top_score() # return top 2 products
```

This allows a more consistent syntax : the related products is always accessed via *products*, *top_score* acting as a filter. Additionally, ProductType class is no more cluttered with Product's query logic.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out product type from Product model slice them like this -

```
    product_type_list = ProductType.objects.value("id")
    for product_type in product_type_list:
        Product.objects.filter(
            product_type=product_type
        ).order_by("-score")[0:2]
```